# dynamic upload form only uploads one file

Tags: php, jquery, file, upload

A form with one upload link already defined

```
<form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
Files to upload 
 <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple/><br>
    <button class="add_more">Add More Files</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="upload"/>
</form>
```

and I can add more links for more files if i wish

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add_more').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).before("<input name='file[]' type='file'/ multiple><br>");
    });
});
```

but after adding more links and files , when i process the form $_FILES array only contains the first file , from the link defined originally in the html.

the var_dump($_FILES)  output is after uploading the file is

> array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "xxxxxCV.doc" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "application/msword" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phph4u15e" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(63488) } } }

Is there a way to dynamically add file uploads that end up in $_FILES ?

If i put multiple file upload lines in the html  and dont use the jquery adding a link, $_FILES contains multiple files .

`max_file_uploads = 20` (php.ini)

there are (to me at least) good reasons why I need to store the files in the database  rather than as a link

if i create a form with 2,3,4 etc links
ie

```
<input name="file[]" type="file" multiple/><br>
<input name="file[]" type="file" multiple/><br>
<input name="file[]" type="file" multiple/><br>
    <button class="add_more">Add More Files</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="upload"/>
</form>
```

i can upload the  files and they are in $_FILES.
If i start with one link and add more with jquery, 
only the file uploaded  from the original HTML ( not those add with jquery) 
is in $_FILES

Comment: There is a great plugin for file uploads; [Dropzone JS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

Comment: if i understand you correctly ... if you use var_dump($_POST['file']).. so you dont help to you? Or what is your problem. I dont understant this "If i put multiple file upload lines in the html and dont use the jquery adding a link, $_FILES contains multiple files"

Comment: > If I have 2 links in the HTML  <input name="file[]" type="file"
> multiple/><br> <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple/><br>
>     <button class="add_more">Add More Files</button>
>     <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="upload"/> </form>
i can upload 2 files  . 3 links , up to 3 files etc etc . 

If i start with 1 file( or 2)  upload link and  add more upload links with jquery and then add files to upload ,  only 1 ( or 2) file is listed in the $_FILES array, 

ie files that are added to the upload by creating the link with jquery are not listed in $_FILES